# Reaction mechanism of lithiated benzene and oxygen in acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, organometallic-compounds

According to (1) addition of O<sub>2</sub> in acid to lithiated benzene makes phenol.

I'm trying to deduce the mechanism, and somehow it doesn't feel right but I'm not sure.

[image]

(1) Snieckus, V. Directed ortho metalation. Tertiary amide and O-carbamate directors in synthetic strategies for polysubstituted aromatics. *Chem. Rev.* **1990,** *90* (6), 879–933. [DOI: 10.1021/cr00104a001](https://doi.org/10.1021/cr00104a001).

Comment: Addition of oxygen followed by acid work up, not oxygen in acid

Comment: Your proposed mechanism doesn't quite work; loss of H2O would lead to a six-electron oxygen species (that should already set off alarm bells), and to get back its octet, that oxygen would have to pick up the equivalent of a hydride, not a proton (from water). Based on the original paper https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo00380a034 that Snieckus cites there isn't any attempt to generate singlet O2, so I imagine that the mechanism is (at least partly) radical, but I don't have a concrete suggestion in mind.

Comment: In addition, @Waylander's comment is a very salient point which you should pay more attention to, imo: it is oxygen followed by acid, not at the same time (that would be rather pointless, as adding any kind of acidic solution - $\ce{O2}$ or not - to an organolithium would simply protonate it). So we presumably need to react $\ce{ArLi}$ with $\ce{O2}$ (with a radical mechanism) to get to a phenoxide $\ce{ArO-}$, which upon workup forms the phenol $\ce{ArOH}$. Not trivial...

Comment: @orthocresol: There is the possibility that the aryl hydroperoxide generated during workup oxidizes TMEDA. but I am not convinced.